# Faster computation process time of cashier working at different speeds

Tags: performance-tuning

Consider the following simple problem: there is a warehouse that needs to process orders in a given order. The processing is done by the workers ('cashiers') of the warehouse, who work in shifts of max. one cashier at a time. The speed at which the cashiers work differs per cashier and per order that the cashier processes. The goal is to compute, given a list of the weights of the orders and a work schedule, the total processing time needed. There is a max. processing time for the orders (so if it takes longer, we just report this processing time).

I have implemented multiple ways to do this, of which two are shown below. My question is if there is a more efficient way to implement this? That is, in my application, I want to make these computations for a long list of random work schedules, so I am trying to speed-up the computation of the processing time for one work schedule. nb: to be complete, I also included a function that gives a work schedule and a function that outputs a list of working speeds per order for a given cashier, but in reality these functions are more complex than presented here, so the focus of efficiency/speeding-up is purely on simProcessTime here.

Implementation 1:

```
simProcessTime[orderlengths_, maxprocesstime_] := 
  Module[{workschedule, timenextshift, cashiernr, index = 1, 
    workspeed, processed = 0, processtime = 0, timefornextorder},
   workschedule = randomWorkSchedule[maxprocesstime];
   {timenextshift, cashiernr} = workschedule[[index]];
   Do[
    workspeed = cashierSpeed[cashiernr, Length[orderlengths]][[j]];
    While[processed +  timenextshift/workspeed < orderlengths[[j]],
     processed += timenextshift/workspeed;
     processtime += timenextshift;
     index ++;
     If[index > Length[workschedule], Return[maxprocesstime]];
     {timenextshift, cashiernr} = workschedule[[index]];
     workspeed = cashierSpeed[cashiernr][[j]];
     ];
    timefornextorder = (orderlengths[[j]] - processed)*workspeed;
    processtime += timefornextorder;
    timenextshift -= timefornextorder;
    processed = 0,
    {j, 1, Length[orderlengths]}
    ];
   Return[processtime]
   ];
```

Implementation 2:

```
simProcessTime[orderlengths_, maxprocesstime_] := 
  Module[{workschedule, timenextshift, cashiernr, index = 1, 
    workspeed, processtimeundercurrentspeed, toprocess , 
    processtime = 0, position},
   workschedule = randomWorkSchedule[maxprocesstime];
   {timenextshift, cashiernr} = workschedule[[index]];
   workspeed = cashierSpeed[cashiernr, Length[orderlengths]];
   toprocess = orderlengths;
   processtimeundercurrentspeed = Accumulate[toprocess/workspeed];
   While[Last@processtimeundercurrentspeed > timenextshift,
    position = 
     First@FirstPosition[
       processtimeundercurrentspeed, _?(# >= timenextshift &)];
    toprocess[[1 ;; position - 1]] = 0;
    toprocess[[position]] -= 
     Which[position == 1, timenextshift *First@workspeed, 
      True, (timenextshift - 
         processtimeundercurrentspeed[[position - 
            1]])*(workspeed[[position]])];
    processtime += timenextshift;
    index += 1;
    If[index > Length[workschedule], Return[maxprocesstime]];
    {timenextshift, cashiernr} = workschedule[[index]];
    workspeed = cashierSpeed[cashiernr, Length[orderlengths]];
    processtimeundercurrentspeed = Accumulate[toprocess/workspeed];
    ];
   Return[processtime + Last@processtimeundercurrentspeed]
   ];
```

Example functions for work schedules and work speeds cashiers:

```
randomWorkSchedule[maxprocesstime_] := 
  Block[{assistant, schedule, shifttime, time = 0},
   assistant = RandomChoice[Range[10]];
   schedule = Reap[
      While[time < maxprocesstime,
       assistant = RandomChoice[Complement[Range[10], {assistant}]];
       shifttime = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[0.5]];
       Sow[{shifttime, assistant}];
       time += shifttime;]][[2, 1]];
   Return[schedule]
   ];
cashierSpeed[nrofcashier_, nrofobjects_] := 
 ConstantArray[N[nrofcashier], {nrofobjects}]
```

Example input:

```
simProcessTime[{6, 5, 4}, 6]
```

Any hints are very welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: "I want to make these computations for a long list of random work schedules". How long lists, and how many different lists? Orders of magnitude.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thank you for asking, I should indeed have included this. I want to test for 10^6 different lists. Since the lists I will be testing are randomly drawn (as e.g. in randomWorkSchedule), the length of the lists is not a priori known, but will be typically be small (10-30).